# How to acquire a lock among a list of locks as soon as possible?

Tags: java, concurrency

I have this extremely simplified class, running a task under a lock. The lock is there to prevent the same task to run concurrently twice.
The task itself can be run as many times as needed.

```
class Job {
  private Lock lock;
  
  // Constructor, getters, setters, etc. removed to stay short
  
  public boolean execute (int maxWaitTime) {
    if (lock.tryLock(maxWaitTime, TimeUnit.MILISECONDS)) {
      try {
        // do some lengthy job under the lock
      } finally {
        lock.unlock();
      }
    return true;
    }
  else return false;
  }
}
```

Now, let's say that I have a list of these jobs:

```
List<Job> jobs = ... ;
```

All the jobs in the list are of the same nature. I would like to execute only a single one from the list, ignoring all others for the moment.
I want to execute the first available task only, waiting as few as possible after currently held locks (corresponding to tasks currently running).

After a while, let's say 10 seconds, if all jobs are still busy, then I give up and don't execute any (in reality, of course, something different happens in that case).

First, I came up with this:

```
for (Job job: jobs) {
  if (job.execute(10000)) return; // one job has been executed
}
```

And then realised that, if I had N jobs, then I might end up waiting a total of `10*N` seconds instead of only 10 before giving up, in case there's no free job and none become available in the meantime.

Then, I thought about this:

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
while (true) {
  for (Job job: jobs) {
    if (System.currentTimeMillis() -start > 10000) return; // give up after 10 seconds
    if (job.execute(0)) return; // one job has been executed
  }
```

I'm not waiting for a running task and just execute the first available within the 10 seconds, and I'm doing it as quick as possible, that's fine.
However, I'm doing **active wait** here, which is known to be terrible for general performances and should be avoided.

My third attempt is:

```
for (Job job: jobs) {
  if (job.execute(10000/jobs.size())) return; // one job has been executed
}
```

Now I wait at most 10 seconds as desired. But it isn't the most optimal solution.
Let's say I have 10 jobs, the 9th is free, while the first 8 stay running. In that case, I will still wait uselessly for 8 seconds before finding the free one and execute it.

Can we do better ?

As a preference, I would like a standard Java 11 solution without external dependency. The Job class of my example is under my control, so I can refactor it if needed.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: I didn't read through all of this right now but did you have a look at `ThreadPoolExecutor` or if that doesn't fit a priority queue and pop jobs that got started off that queue and into a separate list if needed?

Comment: @Thomas: To make it short, in the real case, the job is a JDBC PreparedStatement, and I want to run the query (with result) on the first non-busy connection. IN fact, I'm already inside a ThreadPoolExecutor task while making the query, so no, I don't want to launch it in another thread, and I don't want to launch multiple times the same query on all connections in parallel.

Comment: Shouldn't connection pools already provide that functionality, i.e. just pick the next query, grab a connection from the pool and execute if you get any.

Comment: Why not use a `BlockingQueue<Job>` instead of a `List<Job>`? The queue could hold all the jobs that are ready to be run. If a thread is ready to run a job, it can `poll(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` for the next job (thereby removing it from the queue, "locking" it for other threads). After finishing the job it can `offer(job)` to put it into the queue again, thereby making it available for other threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is to try to acquire lock for 10 seconds from `N` different threads. If you succeed in it raise a flag (you need to do it thread safe) and if flag already raised release current lock otherwise proceed to execute task.

PS: `N` is number of jobs.

Comment: Isn't it a little dangerous to send N tasks in the same ThreadPoolExecutor I'm already running inside (possible deadlock) ?
From the N tasks launched in parallel, how do I find which one actually finished with the result (I feel I have exactly the same problem of knowing how to wait for multiple futures, the same as with locks)
Is AtomicBoolean suitable for the flag ?
Thank you for your answer.

Comment: You need to use other set of threads. You can record which job was actually executed. `AtomicBoolean` is good choice for flag.

Comment: I hoped there was something simpler, but it doesn't seem to be the case. Thank you, answer accepted.